# Secure way to connect database in website using java servalet JSP or JSTl

Tags: security, jsp, database-design, jstl, database-connection

I want a secure database connection, Best way in java to connect database in my website.I want to avoid hackers to hack my database that's why i want tips to implement database connection which is secure fro outside world.

Comment: These posts might help you - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/656759/secure-jdbc-connection and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3660154/how-are-secure-database-connections-usually-implemented-in-jar-files

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Encrypting your password and other credentials as suggested by @Rajesh is good practice (although not sure why he suggests Hibernate, a great framework but not required for a secure connection).  But your connection to the database still won't be secure.  However SSH tunneling is a common way to establish a secure connection from an application to a database.

Comment: Now what Will i use hibernate or not

Answer (score 0):

Use hibernate,Encrypt your password and database credential(url,userid,paswd,portno etc)

Comment: what is the purpose of Hibernate?

Comment: Because Hibernate prevents SQL Injection?